# OS X: is it possible to open a window on top with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, software

So I have this little script that, when launched does a screenshot of the current screen and then fires up an image editor to edit the image. However, I noticed that every time the editor is being fired up, it just hangs in the background — as in, it doesn't pop up on my screen so sometimes I just sit there wondering what the hell when I suddenly realize I need to do the edits for script to go on and that the image editor is already waiting on me to find it in Dock. Is there a way to make it start on top of other windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tell application "name" to activate`, where `name` is the *name* of the application you want brought to the front. If you already have a `tell` *statement* block for the target application you can use `activate` by itself within the `tell` *statement* block.

Examples:

```
tell application "name" to activate
```

Or:

```
tell application "name"
    activate
    # Other commands to follow...
end tell
```

Also, if the target app is being opened from within a *shell* script, whether executed manually in Terminal or within AppleScript e.g. `do shell script "name.sh ..."` you can add an AppleScript *command* within the *shell* script using `osascript` as in the following:

Syntax:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "name" to activate'
```

Example:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to activate'
```

Note: In Terminal, type `man osascript` and press *enter*, to display the BSD General Commands Manual entry for `osascript`.

---

From the AppleScript Language Guide:

> [**activate**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW60)
>
> ---
>
> Brings an application to the front, launching it if necessary.

---

As a good reference, have a look at [Introduction to AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1) and the following document is handy to have on your system, [AppleScript Language Guide (2013) PDF](https://applescriptlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/applescriptlanguageguide-2013.pdf).

Comment: what if an app starts as an argument inside another script? i.e. my script goes 'do shell script smth.sh -i editor'

Comment: @Arthmost, If the target app is already running, regardless of how it was opened, before the different _script_ tells it to _activate_, then the _frontmost_ window of the target app should be brought  _frontmost_ of all other windows except for a _modal_ window.

Comment: it's not running. what the script inside my script does is launches an editor app to edit the screenshot and it always launches in the background

Comment: @Arthmost, I'd suggest adding the _code_ for your _script(s)_ related to this question within the body of your question so it can be evaluated to accommodate the situation.

Comment: @Arthmost, I've updated my answer adding the use of the `activate` _command_ from within a _shell_ script.  It may be of interest to you.

Comment: my script is as simple as `do shell script "script.sh -i editor"` where `script.sh` take a screenshot and fires up `editor` to edit it. It's not my script, I found it on GitHub.

Comment: @Arthmost, I've updated my answer with additional information and cannot comment further on your particular use case without seeing the _code_!