# Auto-launch the Info Sheet after a screenshot is captured? (by way of script, automation or app etc?)

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I use the command+shift+4 feature constantly for genealogy research, and have this problem whereby I forget where I took the picture from.  To fix this, I'd love it if the Info Sheet could launch immediately after taking the screenshot, so as to remind me to manually cut-paste the URL I took the image from into the comments box within Info Sheet.  Any suggestions on how best to do this would be terrific.  Thanks in advance!

edit: added "shift" above and clarified wording for intended use (cut-and-paste text into comments box).  All this is is a self-reminder for me, by displaying Info Sheet automatically after screenshots are captured -- if this can be done at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a few seconds to do its thing, but you can use a folder action.

If you are using Mojave or later, a destination folder for the screenshots can be set by using the `Options` menu of the **Screenshot.app**.

Create a `folder action` document in Automator, setting it to receive files added to the screenshot folder, and add a **Run AppleScript** action:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with anItem in the input
        tell application "Finder"
            activate
            open information window of anItem
        and tell
    end repeat

    return input
end run
```

Comment: If all that's going to be done through automation is open the Info... then `return input` is not necessary.

Comment: Correct.  I usually just leave that there in case other actions are added, for example copying something to the clipboard or moving file(s).

Comment: You guys are geniuses.  The one thing missing was to bring it to front, which I figured out how to do via [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248216/os-x-is-it-possible-to-open-a-window-on-top-with-applescript).  The answer is to simply add one line before "tell application "Finder" to open" line, above, that line being: tell application "Finder" to activate.  You guys are great.  Thanks a million!!  This works perfectly for my needs.